# Angular 1.6/DatePicker - fire function with onChange event

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

This is a bit of clean but legacy code, and I'm a back-end dev who works with React & Vue at times but need some help on the exact syntax to get this going.

Problem: When datePicker value changes, it should fire an event that makes an ajax call, but is not doing so.

I have an html form with:

```
                <td>
                    <input type='text'
                           ng-model='sd.parameters.production_lock_end_date'
                           ng-change='updatePlanningParameters(sd.parameters.id,sd.parameters)' 
                           ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" 
                           data-provide="datepicker" 
                           data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" 
                           required>
                </td>
```

There is a controller js file with:

```
$scope.updatePlanningParameters = function(itemLocationID, parameters) {
    dataFactory.putItemLocation(itemLocationID, parameters)
        .success(function(data,status) {
            if (status == 200 && data.status == 200 ){
                console.log('Item Location successfully updated.');
            } else if ( status == 200 && data.status != 200 ) {
                console.error('There was some unknown error updating the item location')
            }

        }) 
        .error(function(data,status) {
            console.error('Error getting forecast parameters: ' + error.message);
        });
}
```

There are a half dozen other elements that are normal text inputs and this all works fine. There seems to be some sort of timing issue or something when datePicker is involved.

I have spent half a day researching & it seems to me the solution is to add a $scope.$watch similar to this example:

```
$scope.startdate;

$scope.$watch("startdate", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log("I've changed : ", startdate);
});
```

But I simply cannot get the syntax to work out correctly (and am not even certain that's the correct solution; just what I've come up with)

TIA!

Comment: have you tried `$scope.watch('sd.parameters.production_lock_end_date'` ...?

Comment: yes - that throws an error of undefined  "parameters". I may need to post a little more controller code, but hoping there's enough info above to make it clear

Comment: where is the `undefined`? are you still logging `console.log("I've changed : ", startdate);`? because `startdate` is nothing, should be `$scope.startdate` or log `newValue` or `oldValue`

Comment: this blows up:

    $scope.sd.parameters.production_lock_end_date = '';

    $scope.$watch("sd.parameters.production_lock_end_date", function(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log("I've changed this : ", sd.parameters.production_lock_end_date);
    });

Comment: with error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'parameters' of undefined

Comment: what about `$scope.sd = { parameters: { production_lock_end_date: ''}}`?

Comment: $scope.sd = { parameters: { production_lock_end_date: ''}};

    $scope.$watch("sd.parameters.production_lock_end_date", function(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log("I've changed : ", $scope.sd.parameters.production_lock_end_date);
    });  fires on initial load, but not when I click a new date

Comment: Can do do `<pre>sd.parameters.production_lock_end_date =
 {{sd.parameters.production_lock_end_date}}</pre>` somewhere on your template to check if it gets changed when you select a date? I suspect the datepicker you are using is not an angular directive so your model will not update.

Answer (score 0):

You can try for this:
In above context of communication, I am posting this, try to change the datepicker more than 1 time and see this will fire,

```
$scope.$watch('sd.parameters.production_lock_end_date',function(newval,oldval){
//here we can check the value
console.log("newval:"+newval+"oldval: "+oldval);
});
```